# How to align text input correctly in react native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

The Text input is center aligned, how to fix this text input so that it takes input from top left corner

[image: The Text input is center aligned, how to fix this text input so that it takes input from top left corner]

Here is my css for text input:

```css
 /* The Text input is center aligned, how to fix this text input so that it takes input from top left corner */

input: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 4,
    marginRight: 1,
    marginTop: 5,
    fontSize: 18,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: '#E6E5ED',
    backgroundColor: '#F8F8F9',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    height: 150
}
```

Comment: umm... align it with what? Your question doesn't specify what you're trying to do.

Comment: what should i add in my css so that my text starts from the top left corner?

Answer (score 340, accepted):

I had the same issue, but the above notes didn't solve it. There's an **android-only** style property [`textAlignVertical`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style) that fixes this issue on multiline inputs.

i.e. `textAlignVertical: 'top'`

Comment: This should be the marked answer as it is more up to date and actually solves the problem

Comment: Ahhhh I wish this was in the documentation for `TextInput` component - this is totally the correct answer

Comment: is ios solved by default or does this fix work only for android ?

Comment: @dev_ter it's android-only. I *think* iOS is top-aligned by default, though it's been a while since I've used RN so haven't actually confirmed. Not sure if/how you'd middle-align but feel free to make a note or edit if you find out how!

Comment: Awesome, solved the TextInput align problem with `multiline={true}` in android.

Comment: How it can be accepted answer if `textAlignVertical ` is only for Android?

Comment: @Max Looks like the question was edited and the iOS tag added after the fact, possibly erroneously.

Comment: Working in iOS too

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#multiline) for `textAlignVertical`. iOS sets to top by default.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens only on android and multiline enabled with `flex: 1` and `textAlignVertical: top;` will fix the problem. Thank you, Gianfranco!

Answer (score 47):

TextInput has default padding, override it by setting:

```
paddingTop: 0,
paddingBottom: 0
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7823#issuecomment-222627621)

Comment: That was my issue. Also, textAlignVertical isn't a prop according to [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput)

Comment: @shoopi It is, but it's documented under the [multiline](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#multiline) prop.

Comment: textAlignVertical works

Answer (score 34):

I have found the solution that in Android, TextInput style `textAlignVertical: 'top'` works. but in ios, TextInput prop `multiline={true}` works.

Comment: I don't understand how people are happy with the `multiline={true}` "solution" on iOS. I see this suggestion everywhere but what if I wanna have a single line input that's vertically aligned?

Comment: @Georgios set numberOfLines to 1?

Comment: @AliMertCakar `numberOfLines={1}` doesn't work together `multiline={true}`. Press enter on your keyboard and you'll see it changes the line.

Answer (score 23):

The Above Answers either give the for iOS or android, which can be quite misleading so this fixes it for both of the platfoms.

```js
<TextInput
style={{
flex: 1,
width: "100%",
height: 150,
color: "#FFF",
textAlignVertical: "top", // android fix for centering it at the top-left corner 
}}
multiline={true} // ios fix for centering it at the top-left corner 
numberOfLines={10}
/>
```

For Android -

```
style={{
//...
flex:1,
textAlignVertical: "top", // android fix for centering it at the top-left corner 
//...
}}
```

For iOS, add
`multiline={true}`
to the `<TextInput/>` component

Answer (score 10):

Give `textAlignVertical : "top"` that will solve your issue.

```
<TextInput placeholder="Your text post" multiline={true} numberOfLines={10}, maxLength={1000} style={{ borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: "#e3e3e3", textAlignVertical : "top" }} />
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar use case in my iOS app, wherein the `TextInput`'s height was 100 and the placeholder was showing in middle. I used `multiline={true}` and it made the text appear from the top.

Comment: is there a way to make it appear at the bottom?

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me (RN 0.61.5):

```
<TextInput style={{textAlignVertical:'top', paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom:0 }} />
```

Answer (score 3):

Update 2015-07-03: multiline text inputs have now been merged:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/991

The [multiline examples](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/60b56455c4b30cbd0cb29790a7751329576ae8d6/Examples/UIExplorer/TextInputExample.js#L357) that ship with React Native in the UI Explorer should work as documented.

The problem you'll have is that multiline TextInput aren't working correctly yet, and the docs are misleading. Please see this Github issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/279

> "We haven't ported that functionality to open source yet."

There is some code in that issue that gives minimal multiline functionality, so you might be able to get it working with that.

Answer (score 2):

I found out per element inspector, that for iOS there is a `paddingTop: 5` for `multiline` `TextInput`s. This was still applied even though I set `paddingVertical: 15` for all of my inputs. The result was a not centered text in multiline inputs on iOS. The solution was to additionally add a `paddingTop: 15` if the `TextInput` is `multiline` and the platform is iOS.
Now there is visually no difference between single line and multiline inputs on both platforms, Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
[image]

```
import {TextInput, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window'); 


<TextInput 
style={{ borderWidth:1, borderRadius:10,minHeight:100, textAlignVertical: 'top',
 width: width-20,paddingHorizontal:10,  }}
          placeholder={"Enter Email ID "}
          multiline          
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just Incase you are looking for code:**

```
<TextInput
placeholder={'comment goes here!'}
multiline
style={{textAlignVertical:'top', ...otherStyle}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the solution for iOS is not as trivial as one might think.

While on Android you can just add this style:

```
paddingTop: 0,
paddingBottom: 0,
```

On iOS you'd need this:

```
multiline={true}
```

But what if you want a **single line**? This is my workaround:

```
<TextInput
   value={comment}
   onChangeText={setComment}
   {/*The lines below are the important ones*/}
   multiline={true}
   blurOnSubmit={true}
   autoCorrect={false}
   onSubmitEditing={handleOnSubmit}
/>
```

Let me explain what's happening here:

1. As we said, `multiline={true}` vertically aligns the text.
2. To avoid adding a new line after pressing the submit button, you need `blurOnSubmit={true}`. This also closes the keyboard and although in my case that's ok, I haven't figured a way around it, unfortunately.
3. I used `autoCorrect={false}` because without it, the submit button will change the TextInput's value to the automatically selected suggestion (if any).
4. Finally, if you want to perform some action when the submit button is pressed, then you need `onSubmitEditing={handleOnSubmit}`.

What a journey to just align a text...

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a single line input text where I was always observing multi-line, But I found it here for a single line and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const screenWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);
const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);

// ...
intext: {
    height:screenHeight - 10,
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
    fontSize:17,
    padding:12,
    fontFamily:'courier',
    margin:10,     
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's default for iOS, for android in my case adding `paddingVertical: 0,` to text style worked.

Answer (score 0):

For those using `nativewind`, I avoided that the decenders got cutted by playing with the `lineheight` property. I.e. For me adding the class `leading-5` works well.

Answer (score -2):

To get text aligned vertically center on both platforms use:

For android use `textAlignVertical: "center"`

For ios  use `justifyContent: "center"`