# How to centralize text in textinput

Tags: javascript, react-native

One short question.
Is there a way to centralize text in react-native `Textinput`?

Here is the markup in jsx:

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Your Account" />
```

In styles.input, just try to add `textAlign:"center"`, it's not working.

And same as add alignAlign to the markup as an attribute.
Could anybody do me a favor? Thx.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560065/how-to-align-text-input-correctly-in-react-native

Comment: @mplungjan Seems not, mine is <code>textAlign:center</code> in react native(just the same with html input text-align:center) , their question is an issue in multi-line input.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You should use the inputText props to align text to center as below

```
textAlign={'center'}
```

And it will look like

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} textAlign={'center'} placeholder="Your Account" />
```

Comment: textAlign='center' also works and looks cleaner to me

Comment: textAlign is not mentioned in the documentations ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput ). How did you find it out? Are there any other documentations I should follow?

Answer (score 6):

This bug has been around for a while already, but it looks like a fix will be merged soon: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/772

Answer (score 3):

The android-only [`textAlignVertical`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style) may also be a necessary component of the solution. See also: [How to align text input correctly in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560065/how-to-align-text-input-correctly-in-react-native/36020519)

Comment: (Although it sounds like maybe you were aiming for horizontal centering.)