# React-Native - TextInput cursor placed in the middle instead of top in Android

Tags: react-native

I am rendering a `TextInput` in my react-native app which has a height of 100 px. The cursor for typing in the text is displayed in the center instead of the top in Android. The cursor appears fine for iOS. Below is a sketch which demonstrates the problem:

https://sketch.expo.io/SJVIk30ig

The `TextInput` is rendered using below code:

```
<TextInput style={{height: 100, padding: 5, backgroundColor: colorThemes.Blue.lightGrey}} 
          multiline={true}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onTextInputChange}
          underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
          autoCorrect={true} autoFocus={true}
          autoCapitalize={'sentences'}
        />
```

Comment: Found the answer on this stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560065/how-to-align-text-input-correctly-in-react-native. The solution is to set undocumented style property `textAlignVertical` to 'top'.

Answer (score 24):

Duplication of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560065/how-to-align-text-input-correctly-in-react-native)

Set style property `textAlignVertical` to `top` on the `TextInput`

```
    <TextInput style={{height: 100, padding: 5, 
      backgroundColor: colorThemes.Blue.lightGrey, 
      textAlignVertical: 'top'}} 
      multiline={true}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.onTextInputChange}
      underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
      autoCorrect={true} autoFocus={true}
      autoCapitalize={'sentences'}
    />
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked out well. Seems like a problem on the  android platform.

Answer (score 2):

Just add below style to your InputText, please have a look to the code

```
// This is the style for InputText
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
                inputBox: {
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: '#404040',
                    // Setting up TextInput height as 50 pixel.
                    height: 150,
                    // Set border width.
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    // Set border Hex Color Code Here.
                    borderColor: '#404040',
                    // Set border Radius.
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    //Set background color of Text Input.
                    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                    // this for setting cursor to top
                    textAlignVertical: 'top'
                }
            });

    // here is the InputText , we are setting style



<TextInput
             multiline={true}
             style={styles.inputBox}
             placeholder={'Type here...'}
             value={this.state.text}
             onChangeText={newText => this._sendChanges(newText)}
                    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Add `textAlignVertical: 'top'` into your `<TextInput>` styles

Answer (score 1):

we can keep cursor position center using `textAlign:'center'`

```
inputstyle: {
    color: colors.white
    paddingLeft: 4,
    textAlign: 'center',
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `lineHeight` plus `fontSize` to keep the relation between box and text.

Try with the style below:

```
style={{height: 100, lineHeight: 100, fontSize: 100, padding: 5, backgroundColor: 'grey', }}
```

Of course, you need to use the size which fits you better.

Let me know if it works.

Thanks